# hide content on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with basic if then script
https://jsfiddle.net/TeoMorabito/92mtqf54/2/#&togetherjs=3z41zCsyOi

I'm sure it something obvious haha

```
var selectedVal =  document.getElementsByName('select-yui_3_17_2_1_1540352978001_90484-field').value;
if(selectedVal == 'NO')
{var element = document.getElementById('textarea-yui_3_17_2_1_1540167138612_32440');
element.style.visibility = 'hidden';}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to call onChange function of dropdown and then you have to get  the valu of Dropdown by using ID. See the below working code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#yui_3_17_2_1_1540357839233_566').change(function(){
var selectedVal =  document.getElementById('yui_3_17_2_1_1540357839233_566').value;
var element = document.getElementById('textarea-yui_3_17_2_1_1540167138612_32440'); 
if(selectedVal == 'NO')
{
       
   element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}else{
 element.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select-yui_3_17_2_1_1540352978001_90484" class="form-item field select">
                <label class="title" for="select-yui_3_17_2_1_1540352978001_90484-field">Found a Turtle track or nest ?</label>
                <div class="description">if something of interest was found, please proceed to the next section of the data sheet
If no, then scroll to the bottom and submit the data sheet.</div>
                <select name="select-yui_3_17_2_1_1540352978001_90484-field" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1540357839233_566">
                  
                    <option value="YES">YES</option>
                  
                    <option value="NO">NO</option>
                  
                </select>
              </div>

<div id="textarea-yui_3_17_2_1_1540167138612_32440" class="form-item field textarea">
                <label class="title" for="textarea-yui_3_17_2_1_1540167138612_32440-field">Location Description</label>
                
                <textarea class="field-element " id="textarea-yui_3_17_2_1_1540167138612_32440-field"></textarea>
              </div>
```

Comment: Thank you,
The Id of the dropdown is Dynamic,
Is there a way to call for the value NO without mentioning the id (using the name instead) ?

Comment: if you want to get value By Name then you should have to use `document.getElementsByName("select-yui_3_17_2_1_1540352978001_90484-field")[0].value;` like this

Comment: Ok, so I've modified the page and added the correct new ID's to the code
The site is using wordpress and here is the page with the form :
http://seabirdrescue.org.au/sea-turtles/monitoring/

Any idea where and how to add the script,
Anything I do doesn't have any effect.

  $(function() {
  $('#nf-field-44').change(function(){
var selectedVal =  document.getElementById('nf-field-44').value;
var element = document.getElementById('nf-field-45-container'); 
if(selectedVal == 'NO')
{ 
  element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}else{
  element.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
});
});